# How do I list imags from directory?

Tags: php, fileinfo, imagelist

I'm trying to show all images within a specified directory.

The following code lists all allowed file names:

```
  function getDirectoryList() 
  {

    // create an array to hold directory list
    $results = array();

    // create a handler for the directory
    $handler = opendir($this->currentDIR);

    // open directory and walk through the filenames
    while ($file = readdir($handler)) {

      // Make sure we get allowed images types
      if ($this->allowedFileType($file,$this->allowedImageTypes) )
      {
        $results[] = $file;
      }
    }

    // tidy up: close the handler
    closedir($handler);

    // done!
    return $results;
  }

  (...)

 $images = getDirectoryList();

 foreach($images as $img) {
   echo "<li>".$img."</li>"; 
 }
```

How can I get file size and MIME type?
I read that `mime_content_type`is deprecated and I should use [finfo_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) istead. But I've not been very successfull with this.

Do I have to use `/usr/share/misc/magic` to get file information? Can't I use GD library?

I've looked at many examples, but they are old and don't work that well.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the size and mime type of image its simple,

use function : [getimagesize](http://li.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

uses like :

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("img/myimg.jpg");
```

Returns an array with 7 elements.

Index 0 and 1 contains respectively the **width** and the **height** of the image.

Index 2 is one of the **IMAGETYPE_XXX** constants indicating the type of the image.

using [filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) give the size in bytes

Comment: Thanks. That at least gives me the MIME type. But I need the file size, not the image height / width.

Comment: yup, discovered that.
I was just hopeing there might be one file function that hadd all this info.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Haim Evgi's post, use [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to retrieve the dimensions and the image type in an array. Then, use [image_type_to_mime_type()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-mime-type.php) on the image type code to retrieve the MIME:

```
list ($fileWidth, $fileHeight, $fileType) = getimagesize($filename);
$fileMimeType = image_type_to_mime_type($fileType);
```